# Springboot multiple Oracle driver versions

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, ojdbc

For a Springboot project I need to connect to two different instances of existing Oracle databases. The major versions of these databases are too dissimilar that I will need to use two different drivers (I obviously tried anyway).
The specific drivers are and are loaded using maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
    <version>19.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Both drivers are on the classpath and the classnames are identical.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't (at least, not without complicated classloading magic). You can only use one Oracle driver, and I'd recommend using the latest version. Newer versions can still connect to older database versions (though likely very old Oracle version are no longer formally supported, but they might still work).

Comment: I found a wrapper around the Oracle driver in order to get it to work with Springboot. Sadly I think you are correct that I need class loading :(. Thanks for your comment!